# Several PropertyPlaceholderConfigurers with spring

Tags: spring, properties

I have a strange problem with my spring bean definition. My application is a multi-module thing.
At the moment I have a project named core-lib which has a spring.xml file defining a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer like this:

```
<bean id="corePropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="order" value="10" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <!-- default properties files containing ALL possible properties -->
            <value>classpath:default.connection.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:default.mq.properties</value>
            <!-- installation specific, optional properties file containing overridden properties -->
            <value>classpath:connection.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:mq.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Second I have a depending project which has its own spring.xml file including the one from the core-lib project. Moreover it defines a second PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer like this:

```
<!-- import configuration from service layer -->
<import resource="classpath:spring.xml"/> 


<bean id="commPropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="order" value="20" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <!-- properties files containing ALL possible properties -->
            <value>classpath:processing.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Now I have the behavior that a bean defined in this second spring PlaceholderConfigurer can't be instantiated due to missing properties:

> BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'commServer' defined in class path resource [comm-server.spring.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'comm.server.CommServer.port'

If I set a breakpoint in the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class it only get's triggered for the first bean instance and never for the second. Has anyone had a similar setup and can give me some advice?

Thanks,

Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a more comfortable way by defining a new placeholder prefix and suffix:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location">
    <value>classpath:configuration.properties</value>
  </property>
  <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="myprefix{" />
  <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="}" />
</bean>
```

Found here: http://javalibs.blogspot.co.at/2008/04/java-spring-framework-multiple.html

Answer (score 0):

OK I resolved that myself, although I do not understand why this is working so strange.
I have defined a different prefix in the second placeholder (?{ instead of ${) and now its working. I had expected that this would work without any special prefixes...